# NSIncrementalStore loadMetadata

Tags: ios, macos, nsincrementalstore

Granted, this is a stupid question but it's a case of understanding the words but not the meaning.

The documentation for the loadMetaData function in NSIncrementalStore states:

> Any subclass of NSIncrementalStore which is file-based must be able to handle being initialized with a URL pointing to a zero-length file. This serves as an indicator that a new store is to be constructed at the specified location and allows applications using the store to securely create reservation files in known locations.

How are you supposed to handle a zero-length file? How would you recognise a zero length file? Are you not supposed to just create a (database) file or directory at the specified NSURL location?

Comment: NSHipster has a pretty nice article explaining NSIncrementalStore, but I'm not too sure how to answer your question after reading it :\  maybe you can get more out of it: http://nshipster.com/nsincrementalstore/

Comment: No, NSHipster doesn't address this issue. They only talk about remote web stores. Unfortunately I haven't found anything online about this issue.

Comment: I agree though, @MattyAyOh, that NSHipster has a nice article about NSIncrementalStore.

Comment: So are you just confused specifically about how to handle a zero length file?

Comment: Yes @MattyAyOh. I know, stupid of me. Thus far I have encountered existing files, non-existing files, locked files but never zero-length files. Do you just overwrite them? If you are not supposed to write to them, then how do you handle the data and when are you supposed to create your file.

Comment: To me it looks like they just want you to be able to create a zero-length file to 'reserve' the file path?  Sorry I'm not really any help either :\  It's not a stupid question